# Why is my margin css not working in my media query?

Tags: css, margin

I'm trying to create an email signature that when on mobile, the text top aligns with the photo. On the desktop version i have a top margin of 32px, and 0px with the media query. Any clue why my media query isn't working?

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .mobile {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
  }

  .mtext {
    margin-top:0px; !important
    padding:0px; !important
  }
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px; margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px;">
   <tr>
      <td width="100" valign="top" align="left">
         <img width="100px" src="https://www.pkallsc.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Headshot-Jeffrey-Ashley-square-e1522622432938.jpg"  style="float:left;" alt="John Smith" />
      </td>
      <td width="1249" valign="top" style="text-align:left; margin-left:5px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px;" align="left">
         <p class="mtext" style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:32px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; text-align:left;"> <strong>John&nbsp;Smith</strong>
            <br />Chief Executive Officer<br /> 123 Central Suite, Suite 510 |&nbsp;Alpharetta, Georgia 30022<br /> T 800.800.8808 | D 800.800.0236&nbsp;|&nbsp;F 800.800.2704
         </p>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
         <div class="mobile">
         <hr style="border: 1.5px solid #49DBC3; max-width: 550px; margin-left:0;" width="80%" align="left">
         <div>
   <tr> <td colspan="9" align="left"><div class="mobile"> 
   </div></td></tr><div> </div></div>
</table>
```

Comment: Damn son! Have you heard about flexboxes? They may help with your problem. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/    You can make some boxes for your content and then assign the @media for the box

Comment: your code is very bad written

Comment: You should start by fixing your HTML, there are a lot of unneccesary tags in there. Also, it's always best to keep CSS in an external stylesheet, or at the very least in a set of style tags. Inline CSS makes your HTML very hard to read and it's bad for specificity.

Comment: @Kektuto the OP mentions an email signature, so I bet it is about html mails. And email clients are really special and limited if it is about new css features.

Comment: @APAD1 placing the css in the `style` attribute is still necessary if it comes to html emails. But it indeed should not be done by hand but with a build script.

Comment: @DaFois just writing that it is bad written is not really helpful. What do you think could be improved, and what should not be done?

Comment: @t.niese thanks good point. Any tips on improving is greatly appreciated. Yes this is for an html email. Style needs to be inline.

Comment: @ChloeMatthews depends on the build tools you already use. If you have JavaScript based build tools you could use [juice](https://github.com/Automattic/juice) that will do css inlining. But such inliners should exists in different languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .mobile {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
  }

  .mtext {
     margin-top:0px !important;
     padding:0px !important;
  }
}
```

If you need to use `!important` it's should be before `;`